# How to parallelize itertools.combinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have written a code to calculate all possible combinations of elements of a list taken r at a time.

```
for i in itertools.combinations(a_v, tupl):
    i = list(i)
    for pos in range(tupl):
        ft = Q_array[i[pos]]
        ft = np.array(ft)
        out = ft | out
```

For `a_v = range(4)` and `tupl = 2` then i will have the following combinations

```
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[2,3]
```

For all these combinations the following code should run parallely

```
for pos in range(tupl):
        ft = Q_array[i[pos]]
        ft = np.array(ft)
        out = ft | out
```

Is it possible? If yes, how to store and access the results obtained?

Comment: How long does it take to run for a single combination?

Comment: May be helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: for an array of 1024 elements and taking 3 at a time, it takes almost 3 hours or so

Comment: with an array of 1024 and tuples of 3 there are 178433024 combinations. If this takes about 3 hours it means you run about 16'000 tuples per second. Even if you could put that into multiprocessing and let's say you have 4 cores, it would still take you 45 minutes. I would say you need to tune your algorithm before you do any multiprocessing

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the end?